# Large File Size for PSD With Vectors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, file-size

I have a large sign that is 8'x4'. The PSD file uses only text and shape layers, that's it. The file size is 1GB though. Is there any reason why the file size is so large?

I do have many layers, most of them hidden, but they are all text or shapes. I also have an embedded smart object, but the smart object consists of all text and shapes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSD is a raster format at heart. So what happens is that the format keeps a cached copy of all the pixels inside the file. This way the format is compatible with tools that do not support the type layers.

Comment: I tried importing to Illustrator but the files were still huge. Is there a way to convert from PSD to AI?

Comment: For now, since it's vector, I scaled the sign down to 1" tall. It still puts the file at 75MB, probably because of the embedded smart object.

Answer (score 1):

PSDs still contain a raster image for previews and compatibility with other software. **If you don't mind losing this preview, you can reduce the file size by adding a solid colour fill layer at the very top of the document, or by hiding all the layers.** This can reduce the file substantially.

Comment: I tried to add a solid color but it didn't help in Photoshop CC 2017.

Answer (score -1):

Check the file resolution. hit ctrl + alt + i. 72dpi would suffice. youre probably on 300.